# How do you create a worktree with TortoiseGit?

Tags: tortoisegit

Now that TortoiseGit has support for worktrees, how can I go about creating one through the UI?

Answer (score 7):

Starting with TortoiseGit 2.14 there is an enhanced support for worktrees.

There is an option on the context menu and you can also create worktrees by using the drag'n'drop feature of the windows explorer when you drag a repository root to create a new worktree.

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-worktrees.html

---

Before that version, there was no special support for creating/managing worktrees.

However, TortoiseGit supports existing worktrees for daily operations (overlays, log, merging, etc.) which are created using the CLI.

Comment: However as of TGit 2.14, the Add Worktree window does not provide you with an option to create the worktree for an existing remote brach, only new branches. Is this correct?